# InDesign - exporting PDF and viewing it in proof colours?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I exported a PDF from InDesign CS5 - it worked well, no issues with the program or the output of the PDF. My problem relates to color - this area's fairly new to me.

My OS is Mac OS X 10.6.7 Snow Leopard, if that's of any use.

When exporting, I selected ISOnewspaperv264 and it worked - but, here's the kicker - it didn't display as it in Acrobat Pro, except when I previewed it.

I had to use Output Preview to see it as ISOnewspaperv264, then convert colors to output intent ISOnewspaperv264 to get it to look like a printed publication and not in Acrobat Pro's default setting of Monitor Color (I don't really want to mess up the Acrobat settings, since it's a shared computer, not just me who uses the program!)

How would I in InDesign/Acrobat get it to view similar to the printed version upon export?
I know in InDesign I can use view Overprint Preview, Proof Colors but I'm new to this area of digital/desktop publishing so any help would be required.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you do NOT need to alter Acrobat's color settings.

Acrobat will not display Overprint Preview by default.

In most cases, you simply need to choose Preferences > Page Display... and set the Overprint Preview to "Always". This should correct the display issues without a need to alter color profiles.

And you SHOULD change this preference in Acrobat even if you aren't the only users. I really don't know why Adobe has this set to Never by default.